# Getting error message running the contributed command failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm getting the following error after developing an extension.

[image]

Repository is found [here](https://github.com/stefanstranger/vscode-psconfeu2017/issues/1).

Comment: Not related to your question, but I would like to suggest including the error message as text in the first place (instead of or additional to a screenshot) which makes your question easier to find by others.

Answer (score 6):

Change your `registerCommand` to use a `Fat Arrow`, like this:

```
var psconfeuagenda = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.getPSConfEUAgenda', () => loadAgenda(psconfeuuri));
```

I cloned your repo and tested with this update and it appears to be working just fine :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @StefanStranger Why?